# Соответствие стандарта ISO-639-2 и CultureInfo

Tags: c#, стандарт, iso

Хочу написать функцию, выводящую название языка на основании его трехбуквенного кода.
На сайте Microsoft (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.threeletterisolanguagename?view=netcore-3.1) утверждается, что ThreeLetterISOLanguageName содержит такой трехбуквенный код согласно стандарту ISO-639-2. Однако, я очень скоро обнаружил нестыковки, например, боснийский язык в ISO-639-2 имеет код "bos", а CultureInfo предлагает "bsb" или "bsc", которые в стандарте отсутствуют. Как лучше поступить в данной ситуации?

Comment: Перефразируйте так, чтобы избежать вопроса, основанного на мнениях.

Comment: Перефразировать что именно?

Comment: может, вы [перепутали](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amUcg.png) `ThreeLetterISOLanguageName` и `ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName`?

Comment: Увы, не перепутал... Именно ISO

Comment: tym32167, меня там тоже bsb и bsc, только маленькими буквами. У Вас правильно, а у меня нет, к сожалению

Comment: У меня как в этой таблице, т.е. не по стандарту: https://www.venea.net/web/culture_code

Comment: Насколько мне известно, эти данные берутся из операционной системы, какая у вас Windows?

Comment: Windows 7 64-bit SP1